# Logstash date parsing failing when using default target

Tags: date, parsing, elasticsearch, logstash

I can't parse a date field using the logstash date plugin, my config is as follow:

```
if "test" in [tags] {
    csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => [ "value", "received_date" ]
        convert => {
             "value" => "float"
        }
    }
    mutate {
        gsub => [ "received_date" , ".\d*$" , ""]
    }
    date {
        match => [ "received_date", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> [2018-06-19T11:51:20,583][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>"f2d34d84-1ea4-4510-8237-2329a4d1ffba",
>    :_index=>"logstash-2018.06.19", :_type=>"doc", :_routing=>nil}, #], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"logstash-2018.06.19", "_type"=>"doc", "_id"=>"f2d34d84-1ea4-4510-8237-2329a
>   4d1ffba", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [received_date]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Invalid format: \"2018-06-19 11:51:15\" is malformed at \" 11:51:15\""}}}}}

If I add a target:

```
    date {
        match => [ "received_date", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
        target => "received_date"
    }
```

Then it works, but the timestamp field takes the date logstash received the input, which is not what I want.

Why would the target impact the date parsing ?

Answer (score 0):

`timestamp` field is mapped as date in elasticsearch for some reason.

You can delete the `timestamp` field,

```
date {
  locale => "en"
  remove_field => ["timestamp"]
}
```